# Apache HttpComponent Dynamically find server

Tags: java, android, apache-httpcomponents

Helo guys, if this post has already been answered, forgive me, because I tried a lot of search terms and now i find myself with no ideas of search terms.

What I want is :

I have one String Array in my Android project. In this array I have many url's. Some are actually a webserver and others no. I'm trying to iterate over this array and make other array only with the url of servers that not refused the connection. But always I get the refused connection exception and the application stop.

How can I test the url to know whether it is valid or not?
One more time, sorry if this question already exists. I really tried to search this before asking here.

EDIT:

I Will put some sample of my code

```
try{
  for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
    String ip = "http://192.168.0." + i;

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(ip);

    if(!get.isAborted()){
      String response = httpclient.execute(get);//The exception is here
      //..... The code continues .....
    }

  }
}catch(HttpHostConnectionException e){
  Log.e("HttpHostConnectionException", e.getMessage());
}
```

All I want is: If the server refuses the connection, just continue trying, but instead, the exception stop the whole application

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. The involved jar files are from [Apache-site](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
            String ip = "http://192.168.0." + i;
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(ip);

            // Execute HTTP request
            System.out.println("Execute request:" + httpget.getURI());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                // Get the status code of responding from servers
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    // the server accept your request, you can do something. 
                    // For example, display the source code of web page.

                    // Get hold of the response entity
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    System.out.println( entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null );
                } else {
                    // the server refuse your accessing.
                    // do something...

                    continue;
                }
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually did something. But this is way too better. I used InetAddres and "ping" each url.